# I can't access my site via wp-admin

Tags: login

I developed a site six months ago and now need to update it, but I can't access the login page to get in to it.

I get a the following error page:

> This is somewhat embarrassing...

I tried `wp-login.php` at end of URL as well but this also didn't work.

Comment: Try to login over FTP. If you can do that you can start to work out what is wrong.

Comment: i am in the hosts server but not sure where to try and login to wordpress here, what should i be looking for?

Comment: You can't login. You can try to figure out what happened. Make sure all the files are there. Sounds like they may not be. Look around for a .htaccess file and post the contents if you find it. Also, what is your  URL?

Comment: www.childtalk.com.au is the url, i never used cpanel to login to wordpress before, am i in the right area?

Comment: I have looked for the .htaccess file but can't see it, its not in any of the wp-admin, includes or content folders, not in root folder either, could this be the problem to not access the login page?

Comment: It may be a permissions problem, verify if the folder has 755 or 775 permissions.

Answer (score 7):

Try disabling all your plugins by moving or deleting them from your `/wp-content/plugins/` folder. Do this by FTP or by your host's control panel.

If this doesn't work, log in to the server via FTP, and upload a fresh copy of WordPress. This will fix your `wp-admin`, and any other folders or files that have been corrupted.

You can download a fresh copy of WordPress from [WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/download/).

For other solutions, including new login files and database-altering, see the [WordPress Codex page on Login Issues](http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble).

They suggest that, in case all else fails, you post at the WordPress Support Forum. Be sure to give [details of your server setup](/Finding_Server_Info), if you know it, including mySQL and PHP versions, as well as your operating system (OS), browser, and the WordPress version that is causing these problems.

Comment: "upload a fresh copy of WordPress" Haven't found a genius like you!!! Lol xD

Answer (score 5):

- Turn on debugging log in Wp-config.php
- Disable plugins by adding a 1 just before every plugin folder
- Repair all tables from your MySql database (repair is a mysql feature. Repair command does not hurt)
- Check htaccess for bad redirects
- Check folders/files permissions (755,644)
- Add the following in `wp-config.php`

  ```
  define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com');
  define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com');
  ```

Comment: the most logical way to find the exact cause and how to solve.

Comment: The last bullet did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

The same thing happened to me (I couldn't access `mysite.com/wp-admin`). This happened when I installed wpcareer plug-in that requested me root access to my site. I then went to cpanel where my site is hosted and deleted that plug-in.

Every thing was fine then after.

Comment: The same problem happened to me with "better secure plugin", the same procedure solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

For having trouble logging in to your WordPress Administration Panels, review this WordPress

Codex: [Login Trouble](http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble)

Answer (score 0):

Your login screen is  here: `http://childtalk.com.au/wordpress/wp-login.php`

You've done something like what is on [this Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) to hide the `/wordpress/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you have wpcareers plugin and you activated it, then we are facing these problems due to version support issue of Wordpress

Go to your hosting area in file `manager>public_html/wp-content/plugins`, here `public_html` is my root folder of my site `jobsclue.in` and delete that plugin after that relogin

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't login to WP Admin either, message was "404 Page not found". I tried restoring files and database backup without success.

Then using Filezilla (you could use others), I renamed the folder `/wp-content/plugins` to: `/wp-content/pluginsoff`

I changed the permalinks (was changed by something to `index.php`), to the previous setting `year/month/date/nameposting`, and clicked Save.

I also changed the `.htaccess` content in root and WordPress folder with:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I renamed all the plugin folders, such as `akismet` to `akismetoff`. After that, I renamed the folder `pluginsoff` back to `plugins`.

I checked the plugins in WP admin until there is no 404 message. Then I remove the "off" from plugin's name one by one. If you suspect a plugin is corrupt, e.g. the date is changed, it's better to delete it and reinstall it again.

Then the problem solved.